# Telerik Radgrid 'FrozenColumnsCount' with 'GridColumnGroup' set for certain groups, NOT working

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

The latest update for Telerik mentioned that this has been fixed  (http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/aspnet-ajax/release-history/ui-for-asp-net-ajax-q1-2015-(version-2015-1-401)

I am trying to use FrozenColumnsCount in a radgrid which has GridColoumnGroup defined for certain columns.

I want certain columns to remain there (Frozen) while I horizontally scroll. When I do scroll, 'Monday' 'Tuesday' etc (i.e, the ColumnGroupHeaders) do not move along, the 'Band 2' ,'Band 3' columns do move. I want the ColumnGroupHeaders to move along as well with the grouped columns. 
Here's the code I have written . There are 6 columns I want to freeze

```
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RG_Box2" runat="server" CellSpacing="-1" DataSourceID="SDS_Box2" GroupPanelPosition="Top" Skin="Black" GridLines="Both" AllowPaging="True" Width="100%">
            <ClientSettings>
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="true" SaveScrollPosition="true" FrozenColumnsCount="6" ></Scrolling>
            </ClientSettings>

            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Shifts_BedsID" DataSourceID="SDS_Box2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                <ColumnGroups>
                    <telerik:GridColumnGroup HeaderText="Monday" Name="Monday" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                    <telerik:GridColumnGroup HeaderText="Tuesday" Name="Tuesday" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                    <telerik:GridColumnGroup HeaderText="Wednesday" Name="Wednesday" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                    <telerik:GridColumnGroup HeaderText="Thursday" Name="Thursday" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                    <telerik:GridColumnGroup HeaderText="Friday" Name="Friday" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                    <telerik:GridColumnGroup HeaderText="Saturday" Name="Saturday" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                    <telerik:GridColumnGroup HeaderText="Sunday" Name="Sunday" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></telerik:GridColumnGroup>
                </ColumnGroups>
```

Part of the code for the columns :

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MB2_v" HeaderText="Band 2" SortExpression="MB2_v" UniqueName="MB2_v" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter MB2_v column" ColumnGroupName="Monday">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MB3_v" HeaderText="Band 3" SortExpression="MB3_v" UniqueName="MB3_v" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter MB3_v column" ColumnGroupName="Monday">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MB4_v" HeaderText="Band 4" SortExpression="MB4_v" UniqueName="MB4_v" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter MB4_v column" ColumnGroupName="Monday">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

---

Am I doing anything wrong? Basically I want the 'ColumnGroupNames' to move as well when I scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the support (which had expired..rookie mistake) and the Dlls were not updating. I am now running the latest version and can confirm that the MultiColumnHeaders with FrozenColumnCount work like a charm. 
I couldnt find a running example of this scenario so maybe this question can be of help to anyone who needs it. 
Cheers.